# React JS installation getting stuck in middle

Tags: reactjs

"added 1393 packages in 1m"     my react installation is getting stuck in this....nothing is showing after this.... a few days ago I was getting the error of "some packages looking for the fund" run npm fund. But after this, I am getting this error

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: My installation is getting stuck at "added 1393 packages in 1m" at this step......i havent showing after this.

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I waited for almost an hour

Comment: @Krishnadev.V .....its getting stucked att that moment in process

Comment: how did you installed react js ?

Comment: @Krishnadev.V I firstly made a folder...and opened it in VS code and then in terminal ... I used "npx create-react-app my-app"